# jQuery pop up and autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Hi so i have a website which is like a criminal records site and i wish when they click search a popup comes with the person. not a popup lkke popup ads but a popup on the site a lot of sites have one with lkke glass corners and inside its black on the background and the text is like inprinted do you know which plugin i mean? if not you can tell me another
And i have another question so people search uaong a aearch bar and i would like to show people autocomplwte options uaing like jquery is that possoble the php script searches a mysql one if u nwed to know that.

Oh sry for my bad writing im on my phone

ps i dont know js or jquery so plugins and ready scripts is what i want

thanks if u guys could help me

Answer (score 0):

You can read about CSS pop-up here: http://webdesignandsuch.com/how-to-create-a-popup-with-css-and-javascript/ and you can read about auto complete here: http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/